# Default solution import and export solution in CRM dynamics.

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I exported the default solution and saved it to my local drive. Then on the online CRM i changed lot of things in the default solution. For example i added two fields.

I went back and imported the default solution , i was expecting that those two fields should be removed and the old solution should be applied back. But then neither the default solution is seen in my imported list and neither it reverted back.

Am i thinking something wrong ? or this is  a expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,It won't delete any fields that you have created, you need to manually delete them if required. But if you have done any changes on entity forms, unmanaged solution will overwrite that changes, so you won't be able to see any changes that you have done after exporting solution.

Second as you have exported your default solution and re-imported that again, it won't show you different solution imported (because it's same solution right)